# OpenLayers add a json layer to existing map on load

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I am new to OpenLayers ... i have managed to build a layer with several features (draw tools, delete and save buttons).

When the user draws shapes on the image map and press Save, these are stored as a json String to filesystem/database.

Since a user desires to see or re-edit his drawing on the image i would like to fetch and re-draw this json String. My code is as follows:

```
function initialiseMap(){
    var options = {
        controls : [],
        maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(0.0, -72448.0, 142848.0, 0.0),
        maxResolution : 1024.000000,
        numZoomLevels : 10
    };

    map = new OpenLayers.Map(imageEditorID, options);

    imageLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(imgURL, "", {
        url : '',
        serviceVersion : '.',
        layername : '.',
        alpha : true,
        type : 'png',
        getURL : overlay_getTileURL,
        transitionEffect: 'resize'
    });

    map.addLayer(imageLayer);
    var vlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable");
    var previousLayer = getJSONData(); //<<<--- HERE I CALL A FUNCTION TO FETCH STORED LAYER
    ....
    .... // create some tools for drawing & then provide save option ....
    ....
    var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
            title: 'Save', text: 'Save',                
            trigger: function(){                        
            var GEOJSON_PARSER = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();        
            var vectorLayerAsJson = GEOJSON_PARSER.write(vlayer.features);                                  
            sendJSONToServer([{name:'param', value:vectorLayerAsJson}]);
            }, 'displayClass': "olControlSaveFeatures"  
    });
    ...
    ...
```

and the function i would like to built, fetch json String from an XHTML form:

```
function getJSONData(data) {
    var htmlstring = document.getElementById("A3702:imageEditor:getJSONData").value;
    .... ///<<<--- How am i going to add this json String as Layer on existing image?
```

Json String is something like:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[43796,-32494],[43852,-30582],[41940,-30526],[41884,-32438],[43796,-32494]]]}}]}
```

How am i going to maybee parse (serialize/deserialize) json String and properly add it (like e.g. as GEOJson layer) to the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getJSONData(data) {
    var htmlstring = document.getElementById("A3702:imageEditor:getJSONData").value;
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(); //create a format to read/write GeoJSON
    return format.read(htmlstring) ; //parse the GeoJSON to an OpenLayers Feature array
```

then in your initialiseMap()

```
var previousFeatures = getJSONData(); //call your function
vlayer.addFeatures(previousFeatures); //add the features to your layer
```

Comment: Consider looking at the OpenLayers docs the next time, all this information is readily there

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the code provided [here](http://maps.peterrobins.co.uk/files/ol6.html) ?

I tried deleting objects and saving them, and when I refreshed the page they were really deleted. But adding/drawing features and saving the results did not really work. I guess checking their source code will give you quite good ideas on how to progress with your problem...

Comment: I can save objects as described above as json String (this is the native form OpenLayers produce). What i am trying to achive is to add subsequently (when map is revisited) this save layer to the map!

Comment: Doesn't the example I gave you do this?!